# QVector(or std::vector) reserve(or resize) down doesn't free memory

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, stl, qvector

Say I have a `QVector` and I call QVector::reserve for 420000 elements. Right after that I call `QVector::reserve` again for 42 elements. What I noticed is that after doing this, the process still has memory allocated for those 420000 elements. Why doesn't memory get freed when I shrink the `QVector` size to 42?

Take the following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>

typedef QVector<QPointF> PointVec;
typedef QList<PointVec*> PointVecList;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Processing...";

    PointVecList list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4200; i++) {
        PointVec *v = new PointVec();

        v->reserve(420000);
        v->resize(420000);

        v->reserve(42);
        v->resize(42);

        list.append(v);
    }

    qDebug() << "End of processing...";

    return a.exec();
}
```

This code crashes throwing `std::bad_aloc` exception(`Unhandled exception at 0x7729C41F in QtConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0034F5E8.`) on a 32 bit system(as the system doesn't support much RAM for one process).

However if I comment lines `v->reserve(420000);` and `v->resize(420000);` everything works fine. This is how I noticed that if I call `v->reserve(42);` and `v->resize(42);`(after reserving/resizing the vector to 420000 elements beforehand) exceeding memory doesn't get freed.

What I also noticed is that `std::vector` behaves exactly the same.

Is it possible to force `Qt` to also free the memory? If not, is it possible to free it myself, manually, somehow?

Comment: why do you expect `reserve(42)` to free any memory? It just has to ensure that there is enough space, not that there is not more than enough space

Comment: You can try [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) but it's non-binding.

Comment: @tobi303 to put it differently, I want to reserve enough memory to make some operations on the vector. after I make the operations I know for sure how much memory the vector needs, so i need to keep the process on a minimum of memory usage...any hints on how can I do that?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux what do you mean by `it's non-binding`?

Comment: a `vector` does manage its memory for you (to a large extend), if you need full control i would resort to a dynamically allocated c-array

Comment: ...or maybe that is something that can be done with a custom allocator, but I am just guessing, never used one myself

Comment: @JacobKrieg A call to `shrink_to_fit` might change `capacity` to `size`, might reduce `capacity` if it's greater than `size` or might not change `capacity` at all. It's up to the implementation.

Comment: If you don't have enough free memory for that allocation anyway, why are you worried about freeing it?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `.reserve()` and `.resize()`. `.reserve()` never shrinks anything, it just ensures there's space pre-allocated for at least as many elements as you `reserve`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But does resize actually release memory when the number of items to resize to is lower than the vector's size? From Qt QVector documentation: `If size is less than the current size, elements are removed from the end.`. So if it removes from the end, why doesn't memory get freed? If its elements are allocated on stack, memory should get freed, right?...why isn't the memory freed?

Comment: @Jacob Krieg See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there is actual memory pressure it makes sense for the underlying library to not do the work of actually releasing the allocated memory back to the OS but instead keep it around and use it to satisfy new allocations (without incurring a context switch to get it from the kernel) that you are likely to make soon anyway.

Same goes for the OS. Even if the application actually releases the memory there's no point in doing the work of actually reclaiming it until it is actually needed elsewhere (with luck it never will be until the process exits and it can just do a single bulk reclaim of everything).

So, the reason is efficiency. There's a cost involved in actually freeing the memory and there's no reason to pay the cost until you *really* have to - which, in many cases will be never.